# Reading Excel File block by block using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I want to read large excel file in a block of say 100 rows at a time. I am doing this (Pseudocode)

```
 readExcel(String tofile, int start, int end){

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(toFile));
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file); // creating workbook
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // creating sheet

            int rw = 0;
            int cnt = 0;
            for (rw = start; cnt < end; rw++) {
                 cnt++;
                if (sheet.getRow(rw) != null) {
                    Row row = sheet.getRow(rw);

                    // Do Something

                   }
                 }
      }
```

calling readExcel with cnt = 100 and changing variable 'start' to start+100 with each call. Is this implementation correct ?
**Does sheet.getRow() fuction have random access or sequential access?**
Is there a better way to get the required result ?

Comment: Did you try reading the [Apache POI Documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)?

Comment: Is this implementation correct ?

Option A. Yes
Option B. No..


Is this your question..

Comment: @Sankumarsingh Actually I wanted an expert view on the implementation so that if it's novice you can suggest me a better way to get the desired result.